# is it possible to have a unique identify for unique circular queues?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computer-science

I was just going through some coding challenges and basically, the question was whether two lists are the same if we are allowed to rotate them. for instance [1,2,3,4,5] and [2,3,4,5,1] are same but [1,2,3,4] and [3,4,2,1] are not. Obviously, it is possible to get the answer by checking all possible rotations by comparing the lists which will be O(n) for rotations and maybe O(n) to check for equality.

I was wondering if there is any mathematical function that is applied to each individual element such that it preserves information regarding the order and gives a unique value for unique circular queues which can then be used to test for circular queue equality.

(I was inspired by encryption as encryption of two equal strings will be the same and unique)

Comment: You can make a simple one yourself, like rotational shift the permutation until $1$ is the first element, and then find out what is the lexicographical index of this permutation

Answer (score 1):

There is a unique cyclic permutation of a list of integers (or elements of any other [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)) which is minimal in [lex order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). It can be computed by finding every place the smallest element of the list occurs (one of these must be the first element), then comparing every element which occurs after this element and looking for the smallest one (one of these must be the second element), etc.

If the list consists of distinct integers then you only need to find the smallest one and rotate it to be the first element, e.g. $\{ 3, 4, 2, 1 \}$ rotates to $\{ 1, 3, 4, 2 \}$. Since you might have to search through the entire list to find its smallest element this is $O(n)$ operations worst case, but that's unavoidable since it takes $O(n)$ operations just to read the lists.

Comment: true, but what if there are repetitions? This works of course. my question was more along the lines of "is there a function that will return the same unique identifier given the same cycle regardless of the starting points?"

Comment: @RitwickJha: this is still true even with repetitions, it just takes more work to calculate. The function I am proposing is the function that computes this unique cyclic permutation which is minimal in lex order.